# position fixed in the iphone X webview

Tags: ios, css, webview, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

i have a ios webview that encapsulates a website. the webview is 100% wide on all sides. What happens is that my fixed top header (and any other fixed element on the website) goes underneath the notch area of the iphone X.

i have my viewport set to `viewport-fit=cover` and I've tried adding

```
padding: env(safe-area-inset-top) env(safe-area-inset-right) env(safe-area-inset-bottom) env(safe-area-inset-left);
```

to the body, or the main container and it works but of course not for any fixed elements that still go underneath the notch.

i don't want to taylor all the fixed elements to have some extra padding on the top detecting the device model and i was wondering if i'm not aware of some workaround to make it understand that `top:0` should be right at the bottom the notch area.

should the ios webview be set inside the safe area instead that fullscreen or is there something that can be done on the frontend code to avoid this?

thanks

Comment: Currently facing this issue. I will have a go at it and post an answer if I solve it.